# How to Trace the message of Solve::ifun in DSolve?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, inverse-function

I want to solve the D.E. about this:

```
m l \[Theta]''[t] == -m g Sin@\[Theta]@t
```

Then, I use Mathematica and type

```
DSolve[m l \[Theta]''[t] == -m g Sin@\[Theta]@t, \[Theta]@t, t]
```

The result is:

[image]

with the message:

[image]

I just want to find out the equation before Solve:

[image]

after pressing this item, I can trace the stack,

[image]

but I just want the equation before Solve and use wolfram engine on which I can't the item. I had tried some:

[image]

So... How can I typing as less as possible of Command to show the equation ate by Solve?

Comment: Does "the equation before Solve" mean the equation in `Solve`? Just copy it and paste it into your notebook.  Or does "the equation before Solve" mean the equation in `DSolve`?

Answer (score 3):

In this case, you can get a step-by-step solution using [`WolframAlpha`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WolframAlpha.html)

```
WolframAlpha["solve m l theta''[t]==-m g Sin[theta[t]]"]
```

[image]